# Catalog Rules Don't Get Applied on Product Save

Tags: indexing, ee-1.13, catalog-price-rules, bug, magento-community

I'm seeing an issue occur where the catalog price rules aren't getting applied when a new product is enabled and saved at the same time.

When I look in the CatalogRule module, I see that there is an observer on the `catalog_product_save_commit_after` event calling `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer::applyAllRulesOnProduct()`

Digging in to the observer, I see it calls:

`Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->applyAllRulesToProduct($product);`

Digging in to this method, it calls `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule::applyToProduct` for each catalog price rule. This method either deletes the data in the db table `catalog_rule_product_price` for the product if the rule doesn't apply to it, or calls `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule::insertRuleData($rule, $websiteIds, $productIds)` if the rule matches.  The parameter $productIds is an array with product ids for the keys and arrays of website ids as the values.

It's in the `insertRuleData` method that things seem to break down.  In the method the body is largely an if statement that executes two different paths depending on whether the catalog product flat tables are enabled.  If they aren't enabled theres a foreach statement that uses the product id array in a way it seems it was intended:

`foreach ($productIds as $productId => $validationByWebsite)`

If the flat tables are enabled, the $productId array is used in a select statement that appears to be incorrect:

`$selectByStore->where('p.entity_id IN (?)', $productIds);`

You have to wind through a bit of code, but p is set in:

`Mage_Rule_Model_Resource_Abstract::getProductFlatSelect()`

`array('p' => $this->getTable('catalog/product'))` aka the db table `catalog_product_entity`

So, the resulting select statement is basically SELECT ... FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE entity_id in (...website_ids...), as the website ids are the contents of the $productIds array.

This select statement will return the wrong products and the `catalogrule_product` table never gets properly updated.  There's an indexer that depends on `catalog_rule_product` to create the contents of `catalog_rule_product_price`

Looks to me like a core bug?  Am I missing something?

If it is a bug, what's the best practice for fixing it - over-riding the resource model or editing the core (gasp)?

Comment: Just to be sure, your indexes aren't on manual update? Are they applied when you reindex manually?

Comment: Regarding fixing it depends on the update strategy, I'd go for local pool override but then you must pay attention if the patch is still required for the updated version

Comment: The indexes are currently updating via cron/changelog in ee 1.13, but it looks like the same issue exists in the CE branch.

Comment: This definitely sounds like it's a bug. Out of curiosity, have you asked Magento support if they have a patch for it?

Comment: No not yet, I'll put in a support ticket on it as well.

Comment: @davidalger Magento support confirmed it's a core bug, I'll post the fix as an answer to this question shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento support confirmed it's a core bug.  In `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_rule::insertRuleData` at about line 247 the code:

```
if (count($productIds) > 0) {
   $selectByStore->where('p.entity_id IN (?)', $productIds);
}
```

Should be replaced by

```
if (count($productIds) > 0) {
   $selectByStore->where('p.entity_id IN (?)', array_keys($productIds));
}
```

I would guess this will be fixed in the next minor point release due out late November 2013 (1.8.1 and 1.13.1).

**Edit:**

This was indeed patched in versions 1.8.1 and 1.13.1